# Search in Files using recursion and wildcard(*)

Tags: java, recursion, wildcard

I wrote this code to search in files of a path with recursion and implementation of wildcard(*) that support more than one.

my code is here:

```
package filesearch;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FileSearch {

    public void walk( String path, String partOfFile ) {

        File root = new File( path );
        File[] list = root.listFiles();

        if (list == null) return;

        for ( File f : list ) {
            if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
                walk( f.getAbsolutePath(), partOfFile );
            }
            else {
                if(match(f.getAbsolutePath(), partOfFile)){

                    System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
                }
                else{

                }
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean match(String fileName, String partOfFileName){
        if(partOfFileName.indexOf("*") == -1){
                if(fileName.equalsIgnoreCase(partOfFileName))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
        }
        else{
            if(partOfFileName.indexOf("*") == partOfFileName.length()-1){
                if(fileName.startsWith(partOfFileName.substring(0, partOfFileName.indexOf("*"))))
                    return true;
            }
            if(partOfFileName.indexOf("*") == 0 ){
                if(partOfFileName.indexOf("*", 1) == -1){
                    if(fileName.endsWith(partOfFileName.substring(1)))
                        return true;

                }
                else{
                    String betweenAsteriks = partOfFileName.substring(1, partOfFileName.indexOf("*", 1));
                    if(fileName.indexOf(betweenAsteriks) != -1){
                        match(fileName, partOfFileName.substring(partOfFileName.indexOf("*", 1)));
                    }
                    else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(partOfFileName.indexOf("*") != 0 && partOfFileName.indexOf("*")!=partOfFileName.length()-1){
                return (match(fileName, partOfFileName.substring(partOfFileName.indexOf("*"))) && match(fileName, partOfFileName.substring(0, partOfFileName.indexOf("*")+1)));
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileSearch fw = new FileSearch();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String partOfFileName = s.next();

        fw.walk("h:\\" , partOfFileName);

    }    
}
```

But it don't work correctly when I use more than one (*) in execution. please help me

Comment: Are you getting a exception? If so please include it. In what way is it not working?

Comment: So you mean that, for example, if you search "some*file*.xml" and you have a file called "some_1_file_2.xml" your code doesn't find it @Ehsan?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this code suit your needs:

```
public boolean match (String filename, String partOfFileName) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(partOfFileName, "*");
    if (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String partialName = st.nextToken(); //get the first substring contained before an *
        int index = filename.indexOf(partialName); //check if it is contained in your filename
        if (index != -1) {
            filename = filename.substring(index + partialName.length()); //if it's contained, cut the filename to check the rest of the string
            partOfFileName = partOfFileName.substring(partOfFileName.indexOf(partialName) + partialName.length()); //cut the partOfFileName so you can get the next token
            return match(filename, partOfFileName); //recursive call
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I think you should not being asking for every possible position for the * (end, start, the middle), you only need to know if the substring before every * is contained, no matter where it is.
I use a [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to get the substrings contained between * (it breaks a string into tokens, using the character received as a parameter, * in our case). Basically I create the StringTokenizer, get the substring before each * and check if it is contained in the full string: if that's so then I cut both string (filename and partOfFileName) and make the recursive call, if it's not contained then return false. 
Let me know if it's ok. Regards